# What could be stopping my DNS resolution from working?

Tags: 22.04, dns

I've been experiencing strange behaviour on Ubuntu 22.04. I will be watching something on Youtube for example and then the streaming will stop indefinitely and the video will freeze. Then I will try to access another web page and the browser (chrome) will complain that it is unable to resolve the URL. Rebooting solves the problem. This happens to me a lot and I would like to be able to resolve the problem without having to reboot. Does anybody have any idea why my machine keeps losing the ability to perform DNS resolution and how I can possibly fix this without rebooting?

EDIT

As requested I provide the output of journalctl -xe -u systemd-resolved.service

```
Oct 25 11:34:13 yaakov-HP-ENVY-Desktop-795-00xx systemd[1]: Stopping Network Name Resolution...
Oct 25 11:34:13 yaakov-HP-ENVY-Desktop-795-00xx systemd-resolved[495]: Failed to create graveyard IO source: Stale file handle
Oct 25 11:34:13 yaakov-HP-ENVY-Desktop-795-00xx systemd-resolved[495]: Failed to create graveyard IO source: Stale file handle
Oct 25 11:34:13 yaakov-HP-ENVY-Desktop-795-00xx systemd-resolved[495]: Failed to create graveyard IO source: Stale file handle
Oct 25 11:34:13 yaakov-HP-ENVY-Desktop-795-00xx systemd-resolved[495]: Failed to create graveyard IO source: Stale file handle
Oct 25 11:34:13 yaakov-HP-ENVY-Desktop-795-00xx systemd-resolved[495]: Failed to create graveyard IO source: Stale file handle
Oct 25 11:34:13 yaakov-HP-ENVY-Desktop-795-00xx systemd-resolved[495]: Failed to create graveyard IO source: Stale file handle
Oct 25 11:34:13 yaakov-HP-ENVY-Desktop-795-00xx systemd-resolved[495]: Failed to create graveyard IO source: Stale file handle
Oct 25 11:34:13 yaakov-HP-ENVY-Desktop-795-00xx systemd-resolved[495]: Failed to create graveyard IO source: Stale file handle
Oct 25 11:34:13 yaakov-HP-ENVY-Desktop-795-00xx systemd-resolved[495]: Failed to create graveyard IO source: Stale file handle
Oct 25 11:34:13 yaakov-HP-ENVY-Desktop-795-00xx systemd-resolved[495]: Failed to create graveyard IO source: Stale file handle
Oct 25 11:34:13 yaakov-HP-ENVY-Desktop-795-00xx systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Deactivated successfully.
 Subject: Unit succeeded
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 
 The unit systemd-resolved.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Oct 25 11:34:13 yaakov-HP-ENVY-Desktop-795-00xx systemd[1]: Stopped Network Name Resolution.
 Subject: A stop job for unit systemd-resolved.service has finished
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 
 A stop job for unit systemd-resolved.service has finished.
 
 The job identifier is 2877 and the job result is done.
Oct 25 11:34:13 yaakov-HP-ENVY-Desktop-795-00xx systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Consumed 1.985s CPU time.
Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

The unit systemd-resolved.service completed and consumed the indicated resources.
```

Comment: Is there anything of interest in the logs when this happens (ex. `journalctl -xe -u systemd-resolved.service`)?

Comment: @steeldriver I have edited my question and added the output of the command you suggested.

Comment: @steeldriver I can't scroll any further up. The output of the command you suggested starts there.

Comment: @steeldriver The output is already less than it was before. Is this time related?

Comment: @steeldriver using the command ```journalctl -u systemd-resolved.service``` I was able to get some more output. I have edited my question to add one more line of relevant output.

Comment: OK thanks - so I'm not sure I can suggest anything, based on that excerpt it looks like a perfectly normal elective shutdown (just as though someone issued a `systemctl stop systemd-resolved` command)